# Why does ServiceStack authentication use cookies rather than a sessionId header?

Tags: servicestack

I'm loving using ServiceStack, but one question has come up from a colleague that I cannot answer. The Authentication mechanism sets a `ss-pid` and an `ss-id` cookie, which is explained here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions

When trying to access a restricted resource, these cookies need to be provided, otherwise you'll receive a `401 Not Authorized` result.

My question is this. Why use a cookie rather than a custom HTTP header value that includes the `sessionId` or equivalent cookie values? Is it because the cookie inherently has its own mechanism to maintain expiration? What were the design decisions undelying the use of cookies over HTTP headers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP Cookies are inherently sticky and is the most appropriate way for maintaining sessions over HTTP. After the server instructs the client to add a Cookie, every subsequent request that the client makes back to the same server will also retain that cookie - this what enables the Client/Server session.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but my understanding was that servicestack supports multiple protocols like SOAP. So how would this work if you had configured a service for both REST and SOAP?

Comment: Please read the [wiki pages on SOAP Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) and info on [Endpoints](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Endpoints) ask a new, specific question if you need any more info.